# Git: merge full repo with another one

Tags: git, github, merge, synchronization, repository

First of all, i am a completely noob in github...
The problem is that I have a forked repo, and this is updated very often.
How to merge the entire repo with my project?
Also, they created a new branch, how to sync it?

Thank you all and sorry for poor english.

EDIT:
I don't plan to send pull to official repo but only to my repo.

Comment: tried both, is not my case. i need to FULLY merge a repo, all branches, like i'm working on the official, but with my modifications.
Actually, i use:

**git fetch official
git merge official/master master
git push**

if i try to merge anything else, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with more information about which "new branch" was created in the original repo, as well as whether or not you're using a local feature branch for your own changes. Do you plan on sending pull requests to the original repo?

Comment: @Cupcake No, i don't plan to send updates to official repo, but only to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository

```
git clone git@itpsmgit1.magnetimarelli.com:tegra/repo_dir
```

create a local branch tracking the remote newly created branch

```
git branch usrname_activity_dev --track origin/new_remote_branch
```

checkout this local branch

```
git checkout usrname_activity_dev
```

pull from the remote repo

```
git pull
```

You will have all the contents of remote: branch, tags etc

Comment: And my modifications are keeped?